# Computer shuts down right after I push power button (have to push it twice to turn it on)

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, memory

I bought a HP Pavilion SleekBook three months ago which comes with two gigabytes of memory, and I upgraded last week putting one module with 4 gigabytes of Crucial, and have updated Windows 8 to 8.1 version.

The problem I have: When I press the power button to turn it off, it powers down and then when I turn on the computer, it shows the HP Boot logo and then shuts off. I then must press the button a second time at which point it boots normally.

I made a video.

[Video of the notebook](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdWhLKHZ2Nk&feature=youtu.be)

Requested Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: If you take out the additional RAM you added, does it work any differently?

Comment: I didn´t test this.

Comment: @DiegoMacario - You need to do so if you want help.

Comment: But there is one thing, I run out the HP memory test in bios and didn´t show any error

Comment: This happens way too soon to be a windows issue IMO. It is not uncommon for a BIOS to do a "double post" on "cold boot." Your problem is *similar* except the reboot to POST the second time merely shuts down the machine instead. It may be worth looking into a BIOS update from HP or a search for `"cold boot" "double post" BIOS`

Comment: @horatio I´m using the latest BIOS version that I can got from HP site, would I go back to `Windows 8`?Because I run a extended test memory and again didn´t found errors.

Comment: Did you already try replacing the 4Gb with the original 2Gb? You decide which is easier: Doing the simple replace to check if it solves this issue or going back to Windows 8. (I think doing the replace is done in a few seconds, going back to Windows 8 will be longer) Note: Putting back the original 2Gb is just for troubleshooting. It does not mean you should keep this solution but we need to know what causes it.

Comment: I understood but @horatio told one other possible problem, I´m using the 2 gb + 4 gb

Comment: @DiegoMacario: What I am saying is that **if** I am correct, this would happen without any OS installed, so no, reverting to Win 8.0 is probably not going to do anything.

Comment: The reasons vary, but the basic idea is that the BIOS checks some settings, perhaps makes a change, then saves and restarts. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_boot

Comment: And here comes a long history, I decided to chat with the HP support here in Brazil, and the attendant told me to do a hard reset, so I did, and when I turn on my computer for my surprise, my Windows doesn´t boot no more, so I needed to restore using my image, I´ve made 5 contacts and got off my new memory and made test with HD and memory and no errors, so I call for the last time and they told they don´t have image from my notebook, so I need to send, but it will get one month so I decided to install Windows 8 again, my problem about boot didn´t happend.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check your power options.Click on battery icon and click more power options.Click choose what power button do.It goes to sleep when you press it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Solved it:

1. Take the RAM sticks out
2. CMOS battery out
3. Clear CMOS (reset BIOS)
4. Put sticks then battery in
5. Accept default BIOS settings

Maybe it was enough to take out battery and clear CMOS, but I've pulled the RAM sticks also.

Hope it will solve your problem also.